# Docker+Synapse+Traefik v2 stops working when I make a separate backend network

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose, matrix

I'm trying to set up a Matrix Synapse server using Docker and a Traefik v2 reverse proxy.

My setup works if I define a single network in my docker-compose file and have Traefik, Synapse and postgres all use that network.

However, based on what I've learnt about Docker so far, I should put postgres on a separate network (`backed`) than Traefik (`web`). Synapse will then be on both networks. However, when I do so, I'm no longer able to connect to Synapse. It times out eventually saying `Gateway Timeout`.

It's as if Synapse is only listening on the `backend` network.

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
  synapse:
    container_name: synapse
    hostname: ${MATRIX_HOSTNAME}
    image: docker.io/matrixdotorg/synapse:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - SYNAPSE_SERVER_NAME=${MATRIX_HOSTNAME}
      - SYNAPSE_REPORT_STATS=yes
      - SYNAPSE_NO_TLS=1
      - SYNAPSE_ENABLE_REGISTRATION=no
      - SYNAPSE_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - SYNAPSE_REGISTRATION_SHARED_SECRET=${REG_SHARED_SECRET}
      - POSTGRES_DB=synapse
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    # expose: 
    #   - "8008"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /opt/services/synapse
        target: /data
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - web
      - backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.synapse.rule=Host(`${MATRIX_HOSTNAME}`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.synapse.loadbalancer.server.port=8008"
      - "traefik.http.routers.synapse.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.synapse.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"

  db:
    image: docker.io/postgres:10-alpine
    container_name: "synapse_db"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=synapse
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - /opt/services/synapse_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
  
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    container_name: "traefik"
    command: 
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=web"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=${CERTBOT_EMAIL}"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      # Router forwards 443 on WAN to 8443 on host so we don't need root permissions
      - "8443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
    restart:
      unless-stopped

networks:
  web:
  backend:
```

And within Synapse's `homeserver.yaml` file, there is a section that could let me bind to a specific interface, but I have not made any changes so it should listen on all interfaces by default:

```yaml
listeners:
  - port: 8008
    tls: false
    type: http
    x_forwarded: true

    resources:
      # - names: [client, federation]
      - names: [client]
        compress: false
```

If I go down to a single network setup it works. What am I doing wrong with the two network setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traefik doesn't know which IP of the container it should try to connect. You're close with `traefik.docker.network=web` but that's not really the name of the network. The network will get a prefix for the project or stack name.

To hard code the network name, you can use the [name field](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#name-1) in the final network section (this is specific to version 3.5 or newer):

```
version '3.5'
services:
  ...
networks:
  web:
    name: web
  backend:
```

Otherwise, set the project in your label (this is usually the current directory name when using `docker-compose`):

```
 labels:
 ...
  - "traefik.docker.network=your_project_name_here_web"
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I assume the web name needs to updated in both the command line argument to traefik as well as the label under synapse?

Comment: @TimMB the label will override the traefik CLI arg, but yes, it's a good idea to make them all match.